# Classloading conflicts with apache commons classes for app deployed to WAS 6.1

Tags: apache-commons, websphere-6.1

I have an app that uses apache-commons-collections v3.2.1. When I deploy the war file using the WAS 6.1 Integrated Solutions Console I get errors because the commons-collections.jar file in isclite.ear gets loaded before the one that I bundle with my .war file. The problem is that my application requires v3.0.0+ of commons collections. The one in isclite.ear is version 2.1.

So, can I deploy into WAS 6.1 without involving isclite? Can I just drop a war file into a directory somewhere? Is there an option I can select in the process of deploying through the admin interface to skip or remove the isclite.ear dependency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with ColdFusion where a jar in the server was a different version than the one that was needed by my application. I had to call a non-delegating loader (one that doesn't ask the parent to first load the class before loading the requested jar).  The loader I used is open source.  You can find out about it at

http://groups.google.com/group/javaloader-dev

Comment: I managed to figure out a way around my problem by reconfiguring the classloading in WAS to "application first".